# Finding the possibility of drawing the same pattern?

Tags: probability

A jar has 10 red candies and 10 blue candies. Terry picks two candies at random, then
Mary picks two of the remaining candies at random. What is the probability that they get
the same color combination ?

My approach to this problem is find the probability of each individual event happening, but I don't know if this is the right way to go about solving the problem. If someone could tell me the method or way to solve this problem that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your approach would be correct - split it up into cases. Find the probability that Terry and Mary both pick two red candies. Then find the probability that Terry and Mary each pick a red and blue candy. Next, find the probability that Terry and Mary both pick blue candies. Finally, your final answer will be the sum of these probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to doing what the comment suggest, you may use that $\mathcal{P}(2 red, 2 red) = \mathcal{P}(2 blue, 2 blue) $ and $\mathcal{P}(1redAND1blue, 1redAND1blue) = 4\times\mathcal{P}(blue,red; blue,red)$, due to symetry. So, 
$$p_1 = \mathcal{P}(2 red, 2 red) = \mathcal{P}(2 blue, 2 blue) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{9}{19} \times \frac{8}{18}\frac{7}{17}$$
and 
$$p_2 = \mathcal{P}(blue,red; blue,red) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{10}{19} \times \frac{9}{18}\frac{9}{17}$$

Thus $2p_1 + 4p_2 = \frac{9.8.7 + 10.9.9}{19.18.17} = \frac{73}{323}$

Answer (score 0):

The cases that we can exclude are:

- One of them picks two of the same color and the other picks two from the other color. That is, Terry picks two blue and Jerry picks two red, or the opposite.
- One of them picks both colors, while the other picks two balls with the same color.
  So the probability becomes:

$$1-\frac{2\times\binom{10}{2}\binom{10}{2}+2\times\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{20}{2}\binom{18}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

Letting $B_T, B_M$ be the count of blue candies picked by Terry and Mary, respectively, you need to sum over the three possibilities.

$$\mathsf P(B_T=B_M) = \sum_{b=0}^2 \mathsf P(B_T=b, B_M=b) ~=~ \sum_{b=0}^2 \dfrac{\binom{10}{b}\binom{10}{2-b}}{\binom{20}{2}}\dfrac{\binom{10-b}{b}\binom{8+b}{2-b}}{\binom{18}{2}}$$

Evaluate and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the colors chosen by $(t_1,t_2,m_1,m_2)$. Distinguishing the cases $t_2=t_1$ and $t_2\ne t_1$ we obtain the following overall probability of success:
$$p={9\over19}\cdot{8\over18}\cdot{7\over17}+{10\over19}\cdot{9\over18}\cdot{9\over17}={73\over323}\ .$$